# when height/width is set to 100%, the element sticks out just barely

Tags: html, css

When I set the height and width of, say, a `canvas` to 100%, instead of expanding to fill the screen, it expands past the screen just barely so that a scroll bar appears and I can scroll up/down left/right a few pixels even when I set `top` and `left` to 0em.

Is there some reason for this? And is there a way to fix this other than setting the height and width, to, say, 98% instead of 100%?

I am using Chrome 36.0.1985.143

HTML:

```
...
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
...
```

CSS:

```
...
canvas
{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;
}
...
```

Comment: scrollbar takes some by itself. you may put `overflow:hidden` if you don't need space out of screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the `border`.

A height of `100%` plus `2px` `border-top`/`border-bottom` = `100%` + `4px` != `100%` - thus the scrollbar appears.

You could use [**`box-sizing: border-box`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the border in the element's width calculation.

> [**border-box**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing): The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmtaaLgc/)

```
canvas {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```